# Are Red-Black Trees considered Full Binary Trees because of the dummy Nodes?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I would like to know if Red-Black Trees are considered Full Binary Trees because of the dummy nodes. I know there are 'NIL' nodes which are black and CLRS picture seems to indicate their are two such 'NIL' nodes for ever red node on the first level of a general RBT, however I am still unclear about whether these node contribute to the "fullness" of the tree.

In addition, are these NIL nodes usually implemented with a standard BST which initializes each Tree-Node as a BST object:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

or

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Comment: Neither of these questions seems to be of any consequence.  What difference do you think it makes if the tree is "considered full"?  The important thing about the implementation of those NIL nodes is that the exact same object is used for ALL of them.

Comment: Quite right, it isn't really of consequence. I just want to understand better what kind of tree data structures need to be full.